# tailwind isn't overriding values

Tags: reactjs, frontend, tailwind-css

In this code below, I have 2 divs. From what I expect, we should have "hello" in red and "world" in blue. but both of them are in red. I could not figure out why. A solution for that can be using tailwind-merge library, but I still want to understand what is happening here. Thanks a lot.

```
function App() {
    const color = "text-blue-600";
    return (
        <div>
            <div className={`${color} text-red-800`}>
                hello
            </div>
            <div className={`text-red-800 ${color}`}>
                world
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Look into using template literals in JSX. I'm not sure what the current state of things is, but that's my suspect. It's truncating the first div element.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that the final result only depends on the order of the css classes in the file created by TailwindCSS for applying them. In this case, the result css file, will be something like:

```scss
.text-blue-600 {
    color: blue; /* example */
}
.text-red-800 {
    color: red; /* example */
}
```

So if an element will have both the `text-blue-600` and the `text-red-800` classes, **only the last one in the returned css file will be applied**.

You can understand more of this and avoid these errors with `prettier-plugin-tailwindcss` that automatically formats the `className` property of your `html`/`jsx` so that the classes applied first are first in the string.

Example of `prettier-plugin-tailwindcss` use:

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="text-red-800 text-blue-600">
            Hello world
        </div>
    );
}
```

is automatically formatted to

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="text-blue-600 text-red-800">
            Hello world
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to tailwind-merge is to use the [tailwindcss-unimportant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwindcss-unimportant) plugin for Tailwind. It adds a variant, `-:`, that let you make classes with lower specificity, meaning they can be overridden.

Tailwind also has an important prefix, `!`, that can make classes have a higher precedence

You example would become:

```js
function App() {
    const color = "text-blue-600";
    return (
        <div>
            <div className={`!text-red-800 ${color}`}>
                hello
            </div>
            <div className={`-:text-red-800 ${color}`}>
                world
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The `-:text-red-800` class is always overridden by the `text-blue-600` class without the `-:` variant, and the `text-blue-600` class is always overridden by the `!text-red-800` class with the important prefix.

Note, as per the other answer, the order of the classes does not matter so I've rearranged them in this example.